# Memory Management, ARC - what to nil?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

**Background** -

I am using automatic reference counting on a project. The root view is a Table View (Master / Detail setup) showing a list of "slide shows". Click on a table cell and you are taken to the detail view which consists of a Scroll view with views (viewController.view) in it (this is the "slide show"). Each slide show has a front cover and back cover (same view controller formatted differently) that sandwich an variable number of pages. Here is the code to load the slide show:

```
- (void)loadScrollView
{    
// The front and back cover are set in Interface Builder because they
// are reused for every slide show, just labels are changed.
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.frontCoverViewController.view];
[self.frontCoverViewController setCoverTitle:_data.name creationDate:_data.creationDate isFrontCover:YES];
[self.pagesArray addObject:self.frontCoverViewController];

for (int i = 0; i < [self getTotalNumberOfComps]; i++) 
{
    PageViewController *pageView = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
    pageView.data = [_compsArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [_scrollView addSubview:pageView.view];
    pageView.data.imgView = pageView.imageView;
    pageView.slideShowViewController = self;
    [_pagesArray addObject:pageView];
}

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.backCoverViewController.view];
[self.backCoverViewController setCoverTitle:_data.name creationDate:_data.creationDate isFrontCover:NO];
[self.pagesArray addObject:self.backCoverViewController];

[self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:_frontCoverViewController.view];
[self setCurrentPage:0];
}
```

**Problem** -

So Im trying to reuse this slide show view controller so I need to nil and recreate the pages in the middle because each slide show has a different number of slides. Note a slide [PageViewController] is just a view with an ImageView in it. It has more functionality so we need the controller however the main display of the V.C. is the ImageView. I have created the following method to "empty" the slide show before running loadScrollView again with new data. Here is the empty method:

```
- (void)saflyEmptyScrollView
{
for (int i = 0; i < [self.pagesArray count]; i++) 
{
    if (i == 0 && i == ([self.pagesArray count]-1)) {
        CoverViewController *cover = (CoverViewController*)[self.pagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [cover.view removeFromSuperview]; 
    } else {
        PageViewController *page = (PageViewController*)[self.pagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [page.view removeFromSuperview];
        page = nil;
    }
}
self.pagesArray = nil;
self.pagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

**Big Question** -

My main question is do I need to set the ImageView of each of these pages to nil? Or does setting the page itself to nil also free up the memory used by the ImageView/Labels/etc that are used in that view controller?

I tried adding self.imageView = nil; to the PageViewController's viewDidUnload and viewWillUnload methods (one at a time not in both) and I realized that setting page = nil does not call the pages Unload methods. Am I freeing up memory correctly.

I've read a lot of articles but Im still not sure if Im managing memory in the best way possible. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't have to set things to nil. And in this specific case, the setting things to nil is doing nothing.

The line `page = nil;` is redundant, because the variable `page` goes out of scope immediately afterwards anyway. ARC knows this and doesn't need you to set it to nil.

And `self.pagesArray = nil;` is redundant because you follow it with `self.pagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. The second line on its own will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the second part I didn't realize that re-initializing the array was the same as emptying it. So just to verify, to achieve my desired effect I just need to remove each page from the subview and then clear the list (or remove the pages from the list) and now because nothing is referencing it - ARC just frees up the memory?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly for your code, but I would expect that removing all the subviews views from their parent view would be sufficient. You probably don't need to remove them from the array explicitly, because as soon as the array is released (which ARC will do when there are no more references to it) the array will release the contents anyway. In short - its looks OK. I recommend profiling your app it with the Leaks tool to see if there is an actual leak.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I have been profiling however Im new at this so Im not as accurate with the tools as I need to be so I just wanted to confirm. Thanks again@