# Release a NSMutableArray when using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm developing an iOS application using latest SDK and ARC.

I have this variable:

```
NSMutableArray* _previewImageBuffer;
```

And this method:

```
- (void)shutdown
{
    [self stop];
    _previewImageBuffer = nil;
}
```

Is `_previewImageBuffer = nil;` correct? If I do it, what happens with memory allocated in _previewImageBuffer`? Is this a memory leak?

I want to release this object because I need to release the memory used by it.

Comment: Answered here maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621587/155513 You're not alone though, having done memory management manually for so many years, looking at ARC code now is sometimes confusing :p

Comment: the answer you cited is confusing and not applicable here

Comment: Minor details:  Setting that pointer to nil does not deallocate the pointer, it causes the OBJECT that the pointer addresses to POSSIBLY be deallocated -- if no other strong pointers address it.  The pointer `_previewImageBuffer` itself belongs to the "this" object and will be dealocated when that object is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is exactly right. Nilifying an object instance variable under ARC releases the object. Releasing an NSArray, if it causes the NSArray to be deallocated, also releases all its elements.

If you're in doubt or confused about memory management and ARC, you might do well to stop and read up on the facts until you're no longer in doubt or confused. My book has a possibly helpful explanation:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

Answer (score 1):

Under ARC this is not a leak. The memory will be released. When learning ARC you should also look at the difference between a `strong` or `weak` reference.

You should also check out [Apple's official introduction to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).